# HttpHeaderSecurityFilter is being weirdly ignored - it always sets max-age to 0 and ignores all parameters

Tags: hsts

This is the most bizarre tomcat configuration problem I've ever seen. I have the following entry in web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    <hstsEnabled>true</hstsEnabled>
    <hstsMaxAgeSeconds>631</hstsMaxAgeSeconds>
    <hstsIncludeSubDomains>true</hstsIncludeSubDomains>
    <hstsPreload>true</hstsPreload>
</filter>
```

I intentionally put in a weird value for max-age so that it would be easy to see if the configuration is active or not.

And it's activated:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

But it doesn't do what it should do. The resulting headers are always:

```
strict-transport-security: max-age=0
```

which is almost exactly what I don't want.

Any ideas on this? I can't even understand how this could be happening and it certainly goes against all the documentation. This is all with Tomcat 9.0.29, JDK 13. It seems like it should "just work" and seems like a very simple configuration.

To be clear, this is in the Tomcat web.xml (in $CATALINA/conf/web.xml), not in an application-specific web.xml. HSTS preload is for the entire domain (including subdomains which might be on other servers), not for any set of URIs within the domain, so it only makes sense to set preload in the server-wide web.xml.

EDIT: This is with a Spring Boot application. It seems that Spring Boot might be controlling this header and overriding whatever is being set in web.xml. This is unfortunate because Spring Boot is for a specific application in a specific context, whereas this header really applies to the entire domain, or even to sub-domains, and so is beyond any specific web application in a specific context. I think I need to figure out how to get Spring Boot to do nothing to HSTS headers and let Tomcat handle it all.

Comment: Problem is solved. Headers were being set in the Spring Boot app and were overriding the headers set in server-wide web.xml. I understand that Spring Boot applications are often deployed as JARs and in that situation it makes sense, but if it's deployed as a WAR in an app server, the app server should control HSTS headers, because it's an issue that's relevant to the entire domain (and subdomains) rather than to a particular context path. But anyway, that's what's going on.